# Webrequest Disallow AutoRedirect

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, webrequest

In .Net 2.0 how can I disallow AutoRedirect when using WebRequest? I found some source code were there where used an AllowAutoRedirect property, but on my WebRequest there is no such property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast it to a `HttpWebRequest`

```
HttpWebRequest WebRequest =
(HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.mySite.com");
WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

Comment: I'm glad you undeleted this - I was wondering why, given that it shows the cast :)

Answer (score 1):

`WebRequest` itself doesn't have such a property, but `HttpWebRequest` does. If you cast to `HttpWebRequest`, you can set `AllowAutoRedirect` to false.

If your web request really *isn't* an `HttpWebRequest`, please explain what kind of request it is.

Comment: I've noticed that most people use the term "WebRequest" and "HttpWebRequest" almost synonymously. Do you think it's because the FileWebRequest class isn't commonly used?

Comment: @Cerebrus: I've certainly never used it.